# Rust как убрать лишний мусор?

Tags: rust

Когда читаю файл

```
let contents = fs::read_to_string(&args[1]).expect("error: something went wrong reading the file");
```

в консоли при запуске если не нашелся файл пишет

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'error: something went wrong reading the file: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "Не удается найти указанный файл." }', src\main.rs:11:49
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

как избавится от этого лишнего мусора?

Comment: Ну например обработайте ошибку вместо того чтобы паниковать?

Comment: там же except есть

Comment: except это и есть паника, а вы вместо него обработайте ошибку (через match хотя бы)

Comment: под мусором имеется в виду только добавляемая рантаймом `note: ...` часть, правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

Если под мусором почему-то имеется в виду последняя строчка со стандартной подсказкой `note: ...`, то она [пишется стандартным обработчиком паник](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cbe3afece/library/std/src/panicking.rs#L216), а значит ее можно перебить любым своим обработчиком через [`std::panic::set_hook`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.set_hook.html), хоть пустым:

```
std::panic::set_hook(Box::new(|_| {}));
```

Но да, более правильным подходом тут было бы вместо expect использовать любой другой не паникующий способ обработки ошибки.

Comment: я уже решил проблему с помощью match